# Error when creating view with union statement in pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I would like to create a view with a union of parts of two tables.

Hereafter is the statement:

```
create view "test" AS 
select 
ppt.reportingtime reportingtime,
ppt.currency currency,
ppt.channelid channelid,
ppt.transactiontype ttype
FROM preprocessortransactions ppt
union
select 
bm.balancetype balancetype
from balancemovements bm
```

The error message I get is the following:

> Error starting at line 1 in command:
>
> create view "test" AS  SELECT
>       ppt.reportingtime reportingtime, 
>       ppt.currency currency, 
>       ppt.channelid channelid, 
>       ppt.transactiontype ttype 
>       FROM 
>       preprocessortransactions ppt
>       union
>       select
>       bm.balancetype balancetype from balancemovements bm
>
> Error at Command Line:1 Column:22 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns 01789. 00000 -  "query block has incorrect number of result columns"
>       *Cause:
>       *Action:

I am pretty new to pl sql and I can't figure out the meaning of the reported error.

I also tried with listing the column names in between brackets before the first AS operator with no success.

Comment: You need to have the same number of fields for both queries being union-ed. Currently you have 4 fields on the top and 1 field on the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there any way of creating blanks in order to get the union statement to work?

Comment: Which field do you want bm.balancetype to sit under?

Comment: "transactiontype" as you guessed. thank you very much for your input

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: PL/SQL is the in-database programming language for coding procedures, functions etc. This is just SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting blanks as requested by using `NULL`'s.

```
CREATE VIEW "test" AS 
SELECT ppt.reportingtime reportingtime, ppt.currency currency, ppt.channelid channelid, ppt.transactiontype ttype
FROM preprocessortransactions ppt
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, bm.balancetype balancetype
FROM balancemovements bm
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case **union** & **unionall** you should give same table attributes in both queries.

For example:

```
select a,b,c from test
union
--- in this you don't have a,b attribute in your second query, you can use null in their place.
select '','',c from test
```

Note: you can use `'' or NULL` so your query be like :

```
create view "test" 
as
    select 
        ppt.reportingtime reportingtime,
        ppt.currency currency,
        ppt.channelid channelid,
        ppt.transactiontype ttype,''
    from
        preprocessortransactions ppt

    union

    select 
        '', '', '', '', bm.balancetype balancetype
    from 
        balancemovements bm
```

Hope it will help you. All the best